# How does Angular know which Spring Boot REST API to invoke?

Tags: java, angular, rest, spring-boot

For example: I have Angular Login, Register, Logout Components. I also have Spring Boot Rest controllers for Login, Register and Logout. How does Angular know to map -

```
Login Component ==> Login Controller
Register Component ==> Register Controller
Logout Component ==> Logout Controller
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.1.2 and Angular 7.

I researched and found out that `HTTPClientModule` is responsible for contacting REST API and `FormsModule`, `HttpModule` are involved.

I also found out that adding this code:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

to `proxy.conf.json` will integrate Angular and Spring Boot but this is not what I want.

I'm looking for kind of function call to the REST API in Angular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there. The question/problem is not clear to me. Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular never does any mapping of the url to spring controller. In fact, Angular app running in the browser doesn't know anything about the services deployed somewhere on a server.

`HttpClientModule` doesn't know anything about the server side stuff. It doesn't know if you make a request to `api/login` url,  it should go to `LoginController` or something else.

By adding the entry as shown in the question inside `proxy.conf.json`, all you are doing is setting up a configuration for redirecting the call to avoid any `CORS` issues.

So `HTTPClientModule` makes the api call, the angular application looks if there is a proxy set up, if it is the call is made to the proxy target if not, the call is made to the url provided.

Now the services deployed at the `proxy target` come into picture:
When the api call is invoked, it reaches the services base url first: `/api/` which is the path defined in your application : `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api` .

Spring Boot uses Apache Tomcat by default, so every HTTP request sent to a Tomcat web server is processed by a Java servlet.

The Spring [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) provides the below functionalities:

- mapping an HTTP request to a certain processing method
- parsing of HTTP request data and headers into data transfer objects (DTOs) or domain objects
- model-view-controller interaction
- generation of responses from DTOs, domain objects, etc.

> **DispatcherServlet**: Central dispatcher for HTTP request handlers/controllers, e.g. for web UI controllers or HTTP-based remote service exporters. Dispatches to registered handlers for processing a web request, providing convenient mapping and exception handling facilities.

It is the heart of the Spring Web MVC framework; this core component receives all requests to your application. To find the handler that matches the request, Spring goes through the registered implementations of the [`HandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html) interface

Comment: Thumbs up for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks!. hope it gave some clarity

Answer (score 0):

> If you need to optionally bypass the proxy, or dynamically change the request before it's sent, define the configuration in proxy.conf.js e.g.

```
    const PROXY_CONFIG = {
    "/api/proxy": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "bypass": function (req, res, proxyOptions) {
            if (req.headers.accept.indexOf("html") !== -1) {
                console.log("Skipping proxy for browser request.");
                return "/index.html";
            }
            req.headers["X-Custom-Header"] = "yes";
        }
    }
}

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

> And in your angular.json, you need to point your 'proxy.config.js' there,

```
 "architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js"
    },
```

[detailed information is here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.